# Kinematics with non constant acceleration II

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, rotational-kinematics

I'm getting crazy with this problem and I think that it's pretty simple.

> An helicopter's helix is spinning at initial speed $w_0=200\ rpm$, all
>   of a sudden the motor stops and it decreases its velocity with a not
>   constant acceleration of $\alpha=-0,01\cdot w \frac{rad}{s^2} $.
>
> The question is: how many revolutions will it make until it stops?

I know that it can't be solved using regular kinematics formulas because the acceleration is not constant so I tried with the next chain rule:

$$a(x) = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx}v$$

that I've seen in another question where the acceleration depended on the $x$, and you can solve the problem with $a(x)dx = vdv$ but in my case it depends on the velocity $w$ and I don't know what to do!

I'm trying to get something like $a(w)dw= ... $ but I don't know how to arrive. This is my closest attempt:

$$\alpha=\frac{dw}{dt}\cdot\frac{dw}{dw}\rightarrow \alpha dw=\phi dw$$

and here I'm stucked.

I will appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a differential equation that says
\begin{equation}
a(x) = -0.01*w = \frac{d w}{d t}
\end{equation}
What you did with the change of variables is correct, so $w$ cancels on either side. Otherwise you have a first order differential equation to solve.

Comment: Mm but I'm in first course and I'm not supposed to be solving differential equations.. shouldn't be a simpler answer? I mean, I have the initial speed, the final speed and the accelerations due to the velocity... isn't there anything easier?

Comment: I am searching for $\phi $ so you are telling me that $\alpha = \phi$ if $w$ is cancelled? I am really confused!

Comment: $dw/dt = dw/dx * dx/dt = w dw/dx$, $w$ cancels, now you are left with an integral until $w = 0$.